# Navigate between two angular application in the same project

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, angular6, angular-template

I have two different Angular application in the same Angular 6 project. The first application is for the administrator and the second application is for the users, and I have a spring boot project for the back-end. Is it possible to navigate between the two angular application? For example, in the login page when I submit, if I'm an administrator i need to run the angular application for the admin an If i'm a simple user i need to stay in the first application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that.

Configure your server to handle that request.

For example, after logging in if the user is an Admin, navigate to some URL (not angular routing), lets say, **http://your_domain/admin**, and configure your server to deliver another angular application which would deliver the **index.html** for that application.

If you plan to stay in the current application, then you do not need to do anything and simply call your APIs to perform your functionalities.